# Android drawable background tiled 9patch workaround

Tags: android, background, repeat, nine-patch

I have read that 9patch isn't able to repeat (it only stretches). But is there any alternative way to create such drawable?

**Top-left** fixed, 
**Top**  x repeat, 
**Top-right** fixed

**Left**  y repeat, 
**Center**  repeat, 
**Right** y repeat

**Bottom-left** fixed,
**Bottom**  x repeat, 
**Bottom-right** fixed

Answer (score 0):

Create a BitmapDrawable. You can then set different modes (repeat, mirror, etc) separately for different axis.

try these links:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeX%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29

http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html